# While loop with Cython? or Better way to remove the elements that fall into a given range

Tags: python, while-loop, cython

I am basically looking for a **faster/better/efficient** way to perform a piece of my python code.

Here goes a simpler version of my part of code.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.choice(100,80) # randomly select integers
A = np.sort(A) # sort it
B = np.unique(A) # drop the duplicate values
```

What I want to do with this vector B is to *remove* its elements that fall within a given range from the previous value. For example, if I have a sorted vector `B = [1,2,5,7,8,11,20,25,30]` and a range value that I would like to assign is 10, then my code should output `C = [1,11,25]`. (2,5,7,8 were removed because it has the distance less than 10 with the element 1. Next element is 11. 20 is removed because 20 has the distance less than 10 with the element 11. Next is 25 so 30 is removed). You get the idea.

I wrote the code as following:

```
def RemoveViolations(vec, L):
    S = []
    P = 0 # pointer
    C = 0 # counter
    while C < vec.size:
        S.append(vec[C])
        preC = np.where(vec>S[P]+L)[0]
        if preC.size:
            C = preC[0]
        else:
            C = vec.size+1
        P = P+1

    return np.asarray(S)
```

So, now, I can do this `C = RemoveViolations(B,10)`, which works like a charm.

Now, the issue is that this is very slow code in python. I have like a sorted vector size of 1 million and it takes some time to finish this code. Is there a better way to do this task?

If I need to implement Cython, how would I change the code to work in C++ environment? I heard it's not really complicated, but a quick search didn't work out well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of your algorithm is the problem: Here is a solution in pure python that executes under `0.15s` on my 8 years old laptop (your implementation needed 200 seconds; i/e a 1300 times improvement for n=1000000):

```
import random


def get_filtered_values(dist, seq):

    prev_val = seq[0]
    compare_to = prev_val + dist
    filtered = [prev_val]

    for elt in seq[1:]:
        if elt <= compare_to:           # <-- change to `<` to match desired results; 
                                        # this matches the results of your implementation 
            continue
        else:
            compare_to = elt + dist
            filtered.append(elt)
    return filtered


B = [1,2,5,7,8,11,20,25,30]
print(get_filtered_values(10, B))

n = 1000000
C = sorted(list(set([random.randint(0, n) for _ in range(n)])))
get_filtered_values(10, C)
```

You can cythonize this code, or numpyize it as you wish, but it probably will not be necessary.